# Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type. -react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

i cant runing function on render side.
here is my code:

```
    let arr = []
 const handleCountry = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < context.gameAdData.length; i++) {
        context.gameAdData[i].map((element) =>
          arr.push(element._fieldsProto.Country?.stringValue)
        )
      }
      return arr
    }
 // handleCountry() // When I remove the command line, I get what I want, but I need to give this event to the button
```

and here is render side:

```
 <>
        <div className={styles.chart}>
          <button className={styles.button} onClick={handleCountry()}>
            Country
          </button>
        </div>
      </>
```

and here is console print:

[image: console_print]

here is my code view ss

[image: code_view]

i hope i could explain, happy day

Comment: Your handle country should have an event as argument like this
const handleCountry = (e) => {}

and remove the return arr from it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing it wrong. You are directly invoking the function instead of calling it on click, you need to remove the parentheses where you are calling the function on onClick event like this:

```
<button className={styles.button} onClick={handleCountry}>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i tried this way and i can try one more way :()=> handleCountry and it didn't work @Nasyx

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it, What are you trying to say here exactly?

Comment: I tried what you said and differently, I tried the combination that I mentioned in my first answer, but both of them do not work. (sorry for bad english) @Nasyx